# How to build the road network from Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to have the [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) representation of a specific region according to Google Maps via Google Maps API ?